# Why do I sometimes get 5 digits instead of 6 in this TOTP function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication

I am using code from https://hackernoon.com/how-to-implement-google-authenticator-two-factor-auth-in-javascript-091wy3vh3 in my Node app that generates a time based OTP 6 digit code.

It is working fine, however, every now and then it only returns a 5 digit code instead of 6 digits.

```
function generateHOTP(secret, counter) {
    const decodedSecret = base32.decode.asBytes(secret);
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        buffer[7 - i] = counter & 0xff;
        counter = counter >> 8;
    }

    // Step 1: Generate an HMAC-SHA-1 value
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', Buffer.from(decodedSecret));
    hmac.update(buffer);
    const hmacResult = hmac.digest();

    // Step 2: Generate a 4-byte string (Dynamic Truncation)
    const code = dynamicTruncationFn(hmacResult);

    // Step 3: Compute an HOTP value
    return code % 10**6;
    //return code;
}
```

Comment: It might generate a smaller number even than that, just pad it with zeroes.

Comment: Thanks jonrshape - would you mind explaining why this occurs? The code is based upon the official RCF documentation so I would have thought this was taken into account? Also, what would be the best way to pad the int with zeros? Thanks again. Steve

Comment: Why *wouldn't* that occur? For example, 012345 is as valid as any other code. You're just getting a *number* back, how you display that is up to you; I'd recommend reading up on string padding if that's what you're displaying.

Comment: Thanks, you say why wouldn't that occur, however, in the code (and the official RCF) it explains that the number is formed from the 4x bytes, and then you use %**6 to get six of the digits, so I can not see why you would get back only 5. I notice this only happens every now and then?

Comment: Only 10% of positive integers less than 1,000,000 have fewer than six digits, *"only ... every now and then"* seems about right.

Comment: Oh. OK I didn't know that (I am new to all this) so it is strange this is neither explained or handled in the official RCF or the code that uses the RCF to produce one time passcodes. No comments on how to handle this. Guess I need to research further. Also, if this is the case, when you use an official authentication app such as google (the code I am using is based on this) it never generates less than 6 digits. just to add, what I meant was the official apps must be padding the numbers, however, you would have thought the RCF would explain you need to do this, and the code. Thanks Steve

Comment: That's not some deeper insight, that's just how numbers work in a decimal system. You'll get 1% with four digits, 0.1% with three, etc. It's not really related to OTPs or the relevant RFCs. The app never generates fewer than six digits **because it pads them**, I just opened Google Authenticator and the first OTP, literally *for Google*, started with *two* zeroes.

Comment: Got you. So the apps are padding, and I need to do the same. I am currently learning more about handling numbers, bytes etc in JS so will continue to research. Just noticed that there is code missing (its in the RCF) that seems to be doing this but not in the code from the link, however, its not JS so trying to "convert". Thanks again. Steve

Answer (score 1):

the problem is code % 10 ** 6 operation return integer and if the first number of digit is 0 it will be omitted, 1043534 % 10 ** 6 = 43534 (5 digits)